# Skype Web Meeting (Web) App does Not Open - LoginFormManager, NPAPI is not supported

Tags: google-chrome, skype

Skype web based meeting app does not open in the chrome when clicked on "Join the meeting". [image: Skype Meeting App]

In the console returns following error;

```
6:31:35:349, TL_ERROR, , LoginFormManager, NPAPI is not supported,  

 Lync_Client_PreAuth_LoginFormManager$performPreFlightChecks, STACKTRACE:: 
 Lync_Client_PreAuth_LoginFormManager$performPreFlightChecks
 Lync_Client_Controls_PreAuthArea_PreAuthAreaViewModel
 Lync_Client_CoreUx_StartPage$preAuthStart
 Lync_Client_CoreUx_StartPage$$w
 Lync_Client_CoreUx_StartPage$$1J

 Lync_Client_CoreUx_StartPage$$22
 Lync_Client_CoreUx_StartPage$start

Lync_Client_Logging_ConsoleHelper$error @ Lync.Client.Common.Consolidated.js?2017.0303.1001:15033
```

Notes :

- Meeting app is already installed and worked before last Chrome update
- Tried with enabling NPAPI with [chrome://flags/#enable-npapi](http://chrome://flags/#enable-npapi) but
  there is no option to enable

Comment: any updates on this?